# Calling a Terminal Command from a Cocoa Application

Tags: cocoa, terminal, ffprobe

1. I created a Cocoa Mac OSX application in XCode
2. Added a Button to the view
3. While running the application, if i click the Button
4. A terminal command for example "ffprobe abcd.avi" should be called and the results should be passedback to the cocoa application

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSTask. You can find some simple examples of using it here: http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=nstask